# Ошибки макроопределений или препроцессора

Tags: c++, c, макросы, препроцессор

Есть небольшой макрос:

```
#define STD_DECLARE_UNIQUE_PTR_DC(NAME, TYPE) \
typedef std::unique_ptr<TYPE, void(*)(TYPE*)> NAME;
```

В нескольких файлах, он используется, и определяет несколько типов для каждого файла.
Все это дело находится в библиотеке динамической компоновки.
Как только подключаю файл в основное приложение, то выкидываются ошибки на этапе компиляции, якобы тип не существует.

Это говорит о том что макроопределения игнорируются в момент сборки основного приложения, а так же о том что придется выносить макрос из файла `stdafx.h` и помещать куда-то в более удобное место?

Или можно как то вынести `template` этого самого `std::unique_ptr<>` что бы на момент компиляции он все таки был?

Файл отвечающий за макрос экспортуруемых классов/функций:

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>

// Объявить некий тип из си кода, с методом удаления
#define STD_DECLARE_UNIQUE_PTR_DC(NAME, TYPE) \
typedef std::unique_ptr<TYPE, void(*)(TYPE*)> NAME;

#define STD_DECLARE_SHARED_PTR(NAME, TYPE) \
typedef std::shared_ptr<TYPE> NAME;

#define STD_DECLARE_WEAK_PTR(NAME, TYPE) \
typedef std::weak_ptr<TYPE> NAME;

#define STD_DECLARE_UNIQUE_PTR(NAME, TYPE) \
typedef std::unique_ptr<TYPE> NAME;

#ifdef ENGINE_EXPORTS
#define EXPORTS_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXPORTS_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

STD_DECLARE_UNIQUE_PTR_DC(window_unique_ptr, SDL_Window)
STD_DECLARE_UNIQUE_PTR_DC(renderer_unique_ptr, SDL_Renderer)
STD_DECLARE_UNIQUE_PTR_DC(texture_unique_ptr, SDL_Texture)
STD_DECLARE_UNIQUE_PTR_DC(surface_unique_ptr, SDL_Surface)
```

Comment: "подключаю файл" - какой файл? "тип не существует" - какой тип? `stdafx.h` обычно является прекомпилируемым заголовком, писать прямо в нем свои макросы не следует. Чтобы был `std::unique_ptr` следует подключать заголовочный файл `<memory>`.

Comment: @VTT: Любой тип который определяется макросом, 1м параметром, т.е. имя типа.

Comment: Ну целевые типы данных тоже должны быть объявлены  `SDL_Window` например.

Comment: Да, целевые типы определяются в заголовках, а сами функции подключаются в cpp файлах, и делетеры тоже определены.

Comment: Заголовочные файлы, где объявляются все целевые типы, уже должны быть подключены в этом файле, иначе в первом же макросе `STD_DECLARE_UNIQUE_PTR_DC(window_unique_ptr, SDL_Window)` идентификатор `SDL_Window` будет неизвестен. Кроме того, непонятен смысл существования всех этих макросов. Если лень писать `std::unique_ptr<TYPE, void(*)(TYPE*)>` каждый раз, то можно объявить алиас `template<typename T> using sdl_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, void(*)(T*)>;` и использовать его `using window_unique_ptr = sdl_unique_ptr<SDL_Window>;`

Answer (score 1):

Макрос - это просто подстановка вместо одного текста другого.

А получающийся текст должен соответствовать синтаксису языка.

Когда используете макросы, надо исходить из этого. В частности - чтобы перед использованием были объявлены все необходимые сущности.